# data from database show only one item on panel. I want to display the whole row on panel but it doesn't work

Tags: c#

Here's my sample data . retrieve two items to display but panel show only one item.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=Acerv5; Database=Customers; integrated security= true");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from Panel", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Label labelID;
        labelID = new Label();
        labelID.Text = reader[0].ToString();
        Label labelName = new Label();
        labelName.Text = reader[1].ToString();

        //panel1.Controls.Add(labelID);
        panel1.Controls.Add(labelName);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel1);
    }
  conn.Close();
}
```

I did try with flowlayoutpanel also but didn't work. Help pls

Answer (score 1):

You create new `Label` controls in the loop but you don't create a new `Panel` control. That suggests that you only have one `Panel`, so you are adding every `Label` to that. Either create a new `Panel` for every record or else just add the `Label` controls directly to the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

If you do the former then you then you will need to set the `Location` of at least the second `Label` for each record, otherwise they will be on top of each other. Not having to worry about that is one of the reasons to use a `FlowLayoutPanel` in the first place. It would probably be better for you to use a `TableLayoutPanel` with two columns. Then you will be guaranteed to have one record per row without having to worry about locations.

Answer (score 0):

I competly agree with the previous commenter. When you dinamically create Labels, you must specify their location too, otherwise they are created in the same place. If you definitly want to correct this above code, try the following:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source = Acerv5; Database =Customers; integrated security = true");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Panel", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    int top = panel1.Top;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        
        Label labelID;
        labelID = new Label();
        labelID.Text = reader[0].ToString();
        labelID.Top = top;
        labelID.AutoSize   = true;
        Label labelName;
        labelName = new Label();
        labelName.Text = reader[1].ToString();
        labelName.AutoSize = true;
        labelName.Top = top;
        labelName.Left = labelID.Right + 20;

        panel1.Controls.Add(labelID);
        panel1.Controls.Add(labelName);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel1);
        top = labelID.Bottom + 10;
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

I hope I could help a bit.